# Set value of one table with reference from another

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

So here's my problem. I'm trying to set Value of Overtime_Total from table Overtime. And to calculate it i need to Multiply Overtime_hours(from table overtime) and Overtimes_Rate(from table Ovt_rate). And i want to use a trigger to update those values after i insert them values. I have tried these method below. Trigger was accepted. However when i tried to insert afterwards i get erorrs.

P/S : I have not inserted any records in Table Overtime yet.

```
CREATE TRIGGER OVET_TOTAL
AFTER INSERT ON Overtime
FOR EACH ROW mode db2sql

UPdate Overtime
set OVERTIME_TOTAL = OVERTIME_HOURS * (SELECT OVERTIMES_RATE FROM OVERTIME_RATE)
WHERE OVT_RATE_ID = (SELECT OVT_RATE_ID FROM OVERTIME_RATE);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting during insert? I'm guessing your subqueries are returning multiple values? How about `SELECT TOP 1 OVERTIMES_RATE FROM OVERTIME_RATE` and `SELECT TOP 1 OVT_RATE_ID FROM OVERTIME_RATE`?

Comment: You have missed a `where` condition in `(SELECT OVERTIMES_RATE FROM OVERTIME_RATE)` subquery.